# Illuminate database query with date_sub

Tags: mysql, laravel, illuminate-container

I'm struggling with a query using the Illuminate database query builder.
When I use the query the result is not as I expected.
When using the query from the querylog directly with mysql cli, I get the expected result.

With query builder:

```
    ->table('CompanyTools')
    ->select(
        'CompanyTools.toolId', 
        $db->raw('COUNT(CompanyTools.toolId) as count')
    )
    ->whereYear('CompanyTools.date', '>', 'YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))')
    ->groupBy('CompanyTools.toolId')
    ->orderBy('count', 'DESC')
    ->take(1)
    ->get();
```

Result:

```
Array ( [toolId] => 88 [count] => 55 )
```

With mysql cli:

```
select `CompanyTools`.`toolId`, COUNT(CompanyTools.toolId) as count from `CompanyTools` 
where year(`CompanyTools`.`date`) > YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) 
group by `CompanyTools`.`toolId` 
order by `count` desc 
limit 1
```

Result:

```
ToolId: 88
count: 17
```

If I (in the query builder) replace `'YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))'`with `2013` I get:

```
Array ( [toolId] => 88 [count] => 17 )
```

Somehow the date_sub get ignored so the result includes all years

I tried with `->whereYear('CompanyTools.date', '>', $db->raw('YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))'))` without any luck.

I guess I could use php to calculate the desired year, but I would rather get the query right.

Thx in advance

/ j

UPDATE

Replacing

```
->whereYear('CompanyTools.date', '>', 'YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))')
```

with

```
->where($db->raw('YEAR(CompanyTools.date)'), '>', $db->raw('YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))'))
```

solves it. Not clever enough to figure out why, but perhaps the whereYear function is supposed to be used diffently

Comment: Try `->toSql()` instead of `->get()` and check the SQL string that's returned. Maybe you'll spot the mistake.

Comment: That outputs `select CompanyTools.toolId, COUNT(CompanyTools.toolId) as count from CompanyTools where year(CompanyTools.date) > YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) group by CompanyTools.toolId order by count desc limit 1` which is the query I use in mysql cli

Comment: Weird. And if you run the query Laravel created with the CLI it returns the correct result?

Comment: Exactly. Only difference I can tell is that the cli doesn't use bindings.

Comment: Just to be sure, you execute the two queries on the same database do you?

Comment: Yes. I use the builder several times with other queries and this is the only one bugging me.

Comment: Try running the whole query with `DB::select('select CompanyTools....')`

Comment: That gives me `Array ( [0] => Array ( [toolId] => 88 [count] => 17 ) )` which is the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already found out using

```
->where($db->raw('YEAR(CompanyTools.date)'), '>', $db->raw('YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))'))
```

Or alternatively

```
->whereRaw('YEAR(CompanyTools.date) > YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))')
```

solves the problem.

#### But why is that?

For every "normal" query, Laravel uses **bindings**. Obviously SQL functions like `YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))` don't work with bindings.

Normally, you can use `DB::raw('YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))')` and the Laravel won't use bindings. For example in `where()` (Expression is the class `DB::raw()` returns)

```
if ( ! $value instanceof Expression)
{
    $this->addBinding($value, 'where');
}
```

But the `whereYear()` function doesn't do such a thing. It uses `addDateBasedWhere()` and just adds a binding without checking if the value is an instance of `Expression`

```
protected function addDateBasedWhere($type, $column, $operator, $value, $boolean = 'and')
{
    $this->wheres[] = compact('column', 'type', 'boolean', 'operator', 'value');

    $this->addBinding($value, 'where');

    return $this;
}
```

This means the query will use bindings and therefore NOT execute the date calculation at all.